# What causes the oscillation in vortex shedding?

Tags: aerodynamics, fluid-mechanics, vortex

When studying [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqUUbe4GT60) video, I was wondering what actually causes the oscillation? Any source online that I found said that it was from oscillating low pressure zones, but what causes that?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strouhal_number) for an answer.